# Asp.Net Core 5.0 Issue with IServiceCollection services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Travel.Application;
using Travel.WebApi.Filters;
using Travel.Data;
using Travel.Shared;

namespace Travel.WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplication();
            services.AddInfrastructureData();
            services.AddInfrastructureShared(Configuration);

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                options.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter()));
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true
            );

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Travel.WebApi", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Travel.WebApi v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my "StartUp" file and I have an error that says :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddInfrastructureData' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddInfrastructureData' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly
> reference?)   Travel.WebApi   C:\Users\Alexandru\Desktop\WebDev\AdminApp\src\presentation\Travel.WebApi\Startup.cs    26  Active

I just.. am stuck. Why can it not find "AddInfrastructureData"?

Comment: Well what is `AddInfrastructureData` then? It's not a feature of .NET so must be something you have created.

Comment: May be you need a package from Nuget.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could check your guide book if you have missed any packages

and you could check your guide book if you have missed to copy the codes like below:

```
 public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureData(this IServiceCollection services)
        {   
            return services;
        }
        public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureShared(this IServiceCollection services,IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            return services;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a using namespace where the `AddInfrastructureData` resides.

Replace `Travel.Data` with the appropriate namespace from your code:

```
namespace Travel.Data;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
  public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureData(this IServiceCollection servicesCollection)
  {
    //...
    return servicesCollection;
  }
}
```

// Startup.cs

```
using Travel.Data;
```

If the extension method is located in a different project or package add it via right clicking the `Dependencies` submenu of the project and select "Add Project Reference..." or "Manage NuGet Packages...".

[image]

Please provide more info in case that it was not helpful. Is the AddInfrastructureData your own method or an external one etc?

Comment: Are you using an example from this repository (book)? https://github.com/stenbror/VueAndDotNet6/blob/fe94817c6ed647cc893c1a1194b77330ac9ab937/src/infrastructure/Travel.Data/DependencyInjection.cs It looks like a newer version for .NET 6. but the difference is that it has an additional argument configuration.